# topojson - combine county CSV data into shp file for state

Tags: shapefile, topojson, ogr2ogr

I am trying to combine a CSV file of county data with a SHP file of NY state that I got from the [US Census site](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/codes/cou.html).

I've downloaded the shape files.
And lets say for NY, this would be the CSV file:

```
countyid    countyname
1   Albany County
3   Allegany County
5   Bronx County
```

I tried this command with the [CLI](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference) but to no avail:
`topojson -e nycounty.csv --id-property=id -o final.json -- tl_2010_25_state10.shp`

This created just the topojson of the SHP file, but missing `id` from the csv data for each object.

for example Im looking for something like this:

```
{
    "type": "Topology",
    "objects": {
        "towns": {
            "type": "GeometryCollection",
            "bbox": [33869.68649540044, 777514.5705503832, 330846.2264954001, 959743.1205503875],
            "geometries": [{
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "id": 19,
                    "arcs": [
                        [0, 1, 2, 3]
                    ]
                }, {
                    "type": "MultiPolygon",
                    "id": 20,
                    "arcs": [
                        [
                            [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Turning into a head scratcher for me. Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 0):

I write a lot of R code, so everything in the spatial world looks like a nail to me. Here is one approach:

I downloaded all the shapefiles from [US Census](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/codes/cou.html) and then read and wrote out the geojson using [rgdal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/) and using base R to subset to NY state only. This gives an "id" within the geojson and prior to writing out the file you could read in and merge whatever data you were interested in.

```
library(rgdal)

country <- readOGR("tl_2016_us_county/tl_2016_us_county.shp", layer= "tl_2016_us_county")
ny <- subset(country, STATEFP == 36)

writeOGR(ny, dsn = "ny.geojson", layer="NY", driver="GeoJSON", check_exists = F)
```

I then checked this file using [GEOjsonlint](http://geojsonlint.com/) and it looked fine.